# VScode caching Issue? File not showing newest changes

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've never seen this before so thought I'd ask here. My vscode isn't showing the latest changes in a file. When I open said file with vim, the file is up-to-date as expected. If I open that same file in vscode, it shows something else.

I've tried restarting vscode, using the 'Clear Editor History' command to clear the editor cache... I've restarted my machine. Nothing seems to work. Any thoughts?

Comment: are there unsaved changes in the file? close and reopen that tab in vscode

Comment: nope, all files are saved, already tried closing and reopening tab. If I open the file with another browser/vim the file state is as expected